# JSON string decoding issue using Newtonsoft and C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In the (abridged) deserialized json string below, I have a problem reading the "href" field (VS2017, C#).

```
"version": "2.0",
"label": "Production from aquaculture excluding hatcheries and nurseries (from 2008 onwards)",
"href": "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/wdds/rest/data/v2.1/json/en/fish_aq2a?precision=1&species=SAL&aquaenv=SEA&fishreg=0&fishreg=10&fishreg=27&fishreg=5&fishreg=9&fishreg=37&fishreg=34&fishreg=NSP&fishreg=4&fishreg=1&unit=EUR&unit=EUR_T&unit=TLW&aquameth=CAG",...
```

I am using a C# class with the fields for the first three items:

```
public string Version { get; set; }
public string Label { get; set; }
public string EurostatURL { get; set; }
```

No problem retrieving the Version and Label, but the EurostatURL field is always empty. As far as I can see, it's a string field like the two preceding ones, only longer and with the http prefix, but I can work out why that would make any difference. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have anything to tell your JSON library that it should be trying to populate `EurostatURL` from the `href` field?

Comment: deserialisation is generally convention-based, using the field names. So, trivially, "href" is not the same as "EurostatURL". Unless you make a custom rule to match these fields, they won't match. How would the desieralizer know that you intend to translate the field name (which, don't forget, is meant to uniquely identify the field) in the source object into a field with a completely different name in the target object?

Comment: I think you need to decorate your `EurostatURL` by `[JsonProperty("href")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can the deserializer know that `href` is `EurostatURL`? Tell it so, or rename your class.

Rename

```
public string Version { get; set; }
public string Label { get; set; }
public string Href { get; set; }
```

Property

```
public string Version { get; set; }
public string Label { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("href")]
public string EurostatURL{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the JSON property you want to reference :

```
[JsonProperty("href")]
public string EurostatURL { get; set; }
```